# Json object to Google pie chart

Tags: javascript, c#, html, google-visualization

I cannot draw a Google pie chart that has it's `DataTable` populated by a Json object.

This is my code to generate the data object (from my code behind).

```
public string getJsonObj()
{
    Utility utils = new Utility();
    List<Item> dataList = new List<Item>();
    dataList.Add(new Item("Mosta",50));
    dataList.Add(new Item("Naxxar",60));
    string json = utils.JsonString(dataList);
    this.ChartData.Value = json;
    return json;
}
```

Item Class

```
public class Item
{
    private string location = "";
    private int frequency = 0;

    public Item(string location, int frequency)
    {
        this.Location = location;
        this.Frequency = frequency;
    }

    public string Location
    {
        get { return location; }
        set { location = value; }
    }

    public int Frequency
    {
        get { return frequency; }
        set { frequency = value; }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawPieChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.DataTable(document.getElementById("ChartData").value));

        var options = {
            title: 'Test Pie Chart'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart1'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
<div id="piechart1" style="width: auto; height: auto;"></div>
```

Can some one please explain to me why this is not showing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your json it is hard to say if this is the only error. But your callback function isn't specified correctly. You need to change this:

```
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

To this:

```
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieChart);
```

The argument you are passing to setOnLoadCallback should be the function you have specified to marry the data to the html. In this case it is drawPieChart.